# Remove Query String with javascript

Tags: javascript

My url containing some query string "?v=1" 
I manage to clean my url using following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
</script>
```

Anyway I want to process the query even I refresh the page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for onetime only :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) 
{
   var uri         = window.location.toString();
   var newURL      = uri.split("?");
   window.location = newURL[0];
}
</script>
```

Comment: It keeps reloading the page